# What is sql version 662?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

This server support version 662 and ealier. A downgrade path is not supported..

I have vs studio 2010 express + sql 2008 R2 express

Comment: Is [this](http://rusanu.com/2010/11/23/this-server-supports-version-662-and-earlier/) your error?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? That error pops up when trying to attach/restore a database? Trying to attach a database from 2008 R2 to 2008 SP2 maybe? More contextual information would be appreciated.

Comment: @marc_s: check Carnotaurus' answer. There is a known issue with this...

Comment: Hint: upgrade  your express, 2014 express is now available. AMong other feaures that allows 10g per database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> This error message is a bit misleading. SQL Server 2008 supports
>   database version 655 and earlier. But with support for 15000
>   partitions in SQL Server 2008 SP2, databases enabled for 15000
>   partitions are upgraded to version 662.

Tell me if this helps: http://rusanu.com/2010/11/23/this-server-supports-version-662-and-earlier/